# Flask mongoengine for a json api

Tags: python, flask, json, mongoengine

I want to develop a json api using flask-mongoengine, but it seems a litle difficult to return json responses.

This is my view's code:

```
@users.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return json_util.dumps(User.objects.first(), default=encode_model)
```

All this returns is this:

```
["username", "password", "email", "foods", "id"]
```

And doesn't return the objects values. How can I return a list of all my users in json format without having to build a dict manually?

What I would like to achive is something like this:

```
[
 "this_documents_id" : {
    "username" : "superjhondoe",
    "password" : "12345",
    "email" : "jhon@doe.com",
    "foods" : ["hot dog", "pasta", "banana"]
 },
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to:

```
@users.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return json_util.dumps(User._collection_obj.find(User.objects().first()))
```

Depending on the version you use, in mongonengine 0.8 there is a [to_json](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/0.8/mongoengine/base/document.py#L279) method.